# What am I missing when using react popper's usePopper() hook to generate an arrow?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, popper.js, react-popper

I'm trying to follow the example on Popper.js's documentation on how to implement an arrow found here using their usePopper hook:

https://popper.js.org/react-popper/v2/

I tried putting this in a codebox and then console.log the styles.arrow and see that it's printing this:

```
{position: "absolute", top: "", left: "0", transform: "translate3d(50px, 0px, 0)"}
```

So I add this code to my app which is in typescript, it looks like this:

```
 const [referenceElement, setReferenceElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const [popperElement, setPopperElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const [arrowElement, setArrowElement] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
  const { styles, attributes } = usePopper(referenceElement, popperElement, {
    modifiers: [
      {
        name: 'arrow',
        options: {
          element: arrowElement,
        },
      },
    ],
  });
```

However, when I console.log styles.arrow here, it comes back undefined. I'm feeling like there's something wrong here. Have I declared something wrong?

Comment: I have the exact same issue; did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with the example or behavior.

As mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/popperjs/react-popper/issues/418#issuecomment-826088557), Popper doesn't provide any style.
and you must see the [styling tutorial](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/tutorial/)